# How to return out of a function or event in VB 6

Tags: c#, function, vb6, return, return-value

In C# if you wanted to return out of a function you could do:

```
If (Something == True)
{
   //Message Box
   Return;
}
Else
{
   // Do nothing
}
```

How would one do this is VB 6?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In VB6, you write

```
FunctionName = ReturnValue
```

Yes, seriously.

To stop execution of a function, use `Exit Function` (or `Exit Sub`)

Comment: +1. And it's because the `Return` statement in VB6 relates to the [`GoSub` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243378(v=vs.60).aspx), which was dropped for VB.Net. Use of `GoSub` is frowned on in VB6.

Comment: That's not "why" at all.  The "why" is that Basic was designed to follow the precedents set by both Fortran and Algol which influenced Basic's development.

Comment: @Bob77 True. I wasn't giving a complete history of the language development. I simply meant to provide a brief explanation for the OP, who apparently is a C# developer with little knowledge of Basic, and might otherwise get confused by compiler errors when using a `Return` statement without any `GoSub`.

Comment: Fair enough.  I'm constantly amazed anyone assigns all these carpentry tasks to plumbers though.